# How to install run Gazebo dev trunk?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Can anyone tell me the best way to install the Gazebo dev trunk for use with ROS please?

Ideally I could leave the Debian package installed, so updates will work ok.
Then just switch between the two when I load a simulation.

Thanks.

Update: I'm switching back to ROS Electric if that makes any difference.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41063/how-to-install-run-gazebo-dev-trunk?/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Switching back to Electric is likely to break things.

What you want to do is install gazebo (trunk) into your ROS workspace, build it, and then make sure your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is set up correctly, so that you find the version you built from source.

The link for the source download is [here](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo) (bulleted list, not too far down). Take a look at the `rosinstall` and `rosws` tools if you aren't familiar with building from source.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0